# Modifying Toolbar to add new row

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm currently in the process of learning how to create a toolbar. I have searched many areas but couldn't find how to modify the toolbar so that i'll have 2 rows.
1st row for navigation and title.
2nd row for search bar

Example:

[image]

Comment: The search bar doesn't have to live inside the `Toolbar`, it can be a separate element just below it. Perhaps you could have them both inside of an `AppBarLayout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. I removed the SearchView from the Menu and put it into the main layout. My layout xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_home" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorToolBar"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:elevation="4dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/main_home_search"
            android:background="@color/searchBackgroundColor"
            android:focusable="false"
            app:queryHint="@string/main_home_search"
            app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
            app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/activity_main_home_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```